# Okhttp Stream Request to Server

Tags: android, streaming, okhttp

I am currently using OkHttp to send Voice request to server. I record and collect the whole data and then send the request to server.Can I use OkHttp to stream the data request to server while recording itself?

Answer (score 3):

Too late! I am assuming you already found your answer, but for future visitors..

Yes. okHttp can be used send streaming data asynchronously with `Pipe` class of Okio.https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/PostStreaming.java 
Having said that, you can always use `java.io` class with `BlockingQueue<E>`