# How to use OkIo Buffer as RequestBody in Okhttp

Tags: android, okhttp, okio

I'm developing anAndroid SDK and i have to send a post request with raw audio bytes from mic as being generated, I'm currently witting bytes into an OkIo Buffer like this

```
public void onAudioData(byte[] data, int size) {

        buffer.write(data);

    }
}
```

How could use this buffer as RequestBody with okHttp? Is there any better solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814346/okhttp-stream-request-to-server#43406143

Comment: It's similar, but in my case I'd like to send bytes while I receive them in onAudioData, not after finishing recording.